# Human meta rig not spreading hand bones

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, rigify

When I add rigify's human meta rig to a project that has a model imported from SFM, the hand bones to not get added correctly. Instead of being spread out flat, like a hand, they all come in on top of eachother, as depicted below. Loading the meta rig in a new project has the same problem.

I can click the bones individually to pose them but it's time consuming and as I see every tutorial online has the hand bones spread out properly, I guess that it is not meant to happen and would like it to stop.

[image]

This originally happened on blender 2.83 and I have updated to the latest version 2.91 where it continues to happen.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this file has been accidentally overwritten:

[image]

You can delete it and copy an original file from another PC.

Comment: Okay, will try that later. Thank you